# Uninitialized Constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compiler-errors, syntax-error, initialization

When I run the following code I'm getting an error that reads "fig_match:rb:5:in '': uninitialized constant Match::Fig (NameError) from fig_match.rb:4:in"

I was in the midst of testing my setup and battle methods, which is why I have the setup and match calls after my variable setters in the Match class.

```
require_relative = 'fig_user.rb' #class name is Fig within fig_user.rb

class Match
    fig1 = Fig.new
    fig2 = Fig.new
    go = 0
    winner = nil

    setup(Bob, Sam)
    match.battle

    def setup(name1, name2)
    #set names
    @name1 = fig1.name
    @name2 = fig2.name

    go = rand(2)
    end


    def battle
        if go.even?
        p fig1.name

        end
    end
```

end

This is the separate class that's being referenced in the above code (not sure if it matters)

```
class Fig 

attr_reader :name, :power, :health
attr_accessor :name, :power, :health

deckId = @id 
name = @name 
power = @power
moves = Hash["Kick", 50, "Punch", 30]
health = 100
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_relative` is a method.  You've assigned it as a variable name.  Hence, you have no Fig class in your scope.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to alter the placement of require_relative. Where would it go to be in my scope? (New to ruby and programming)

Comment: +1, `require_relative = 'fig_user.rb'` should be `require_relative 'fig_user.rb'`

Comment: I imagine you will... For instance, I think the definition for moves will cause some.  Also, attribute_accessor enables both attribute getter and setter functions.  Also, you use `match.battle` where you really could just use `battle` or, to be explicit `self.battle`; assuming I understand what you are after.  Good luck.